# threshold weirdness in latest highcharts version

Tags: highcharts

Here is an example jsfiddle using 4.0.4:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/ge2soL8r/3/

The relevant bit from the above is:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Spline',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [{"x":1424998800000,"y":-8.4,"index":0,"value":-8.3},{"x":1425009600000,"y":-9,"index":1,"value":-9.1},{"x":1425020400000,"y":-8.1,"index":2,"value":-8.1},{"x":1425031200000,"y":-6.6,"index":3,"value":-6.6},{"x":1425042000000,"y":-5,"index":4,"value":-4.9},{"x":1425052800000,"y":-4.4,"index":5,"value":-4.3},{"x":1425063600000,"y":-5,"index":6,"value":-5},{"x":1425074400000,"y":-5.2,"index":7,"value":-5.2},{"x":1425085200000,"y":-5.1,"index":8,"value":-5.1},{"x":1425096000000,"y":-4.9,"index":9,"value":-4.9},{"x":1425106800000,"y":-4.5,"index":10,"value":-4.5},{"x":1425117600000,"y":-4,"index":11,"value":-4},{"x":1425128400000,"y":-3.7,"index":12,"value":-3.7},{"x":1425139200000,"y":-3.4,"index":13,"value":-3.4},{"x":1425150000000,"y":-3.5,"index":14,"value":-3.5},{"x":1425160800000,"y":-3.3,"index":15,"value":-3.2},{"x":1425171600000,"y":-4.4,"index":16,"value":-4.5}],
        color: '#FF0000',
        negativeColor: '#0088FF',
        threshold: 0
    }]
```

And here is the exact same example, just using 4.1.1:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/ge2soL8r/2/

What gives?

Thanks.

Comment: It's already fixed on master branch, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ge2soL8r/4/

Comment: Impressive, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer is that it's a bug in highcharts 4.1.1 that was fixed almost immediately: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3898.  Can either link to the github master branch (see in jsfiddle.net/ge2soL8r/4) or I guess wait for 4.1.2.